# What's the best way to include templates with AngularJS + Webpack2?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, templates, typescript, webpack-2

**EDIT: I haven't found a way to import templates with an `import` statement instead of `require`, but I have discovered that I can simplify my configuration.**

In the webpack config, use `html-loader` instead of `ngtemplate-loader` for `/\.html$/`. Then, in the component, require the template at the top of the file like we did in the original post, *but change "templateUrl" to "template" in the component definition.* Webpack will do the rest for you.

```
const template = require('./component.html');

class Example(){
    ...    
}

export const component = {
    bindings: {},
    controller: Example,
    template: template
};
```

---

**original post:**

I have a working solution with [ngtemplate-loader](https://github.com/WearyMonkey/ngtemplate-loader):

```
const template = require('./component.html');
import ExampleService from './example.service';

class Example() {
    constructor(private exampleService: ExampleService) {

    }
    ...
}

export const component = {
    bindings: {},
    controller: Example,
    templateUrl: template
};
```

But I'm afraid my colleagues will object to the `require` syntax. You see, I am migrating our app from Grunt to Webpack2, and the current app only uses `import foo from './bar'` syntax.

We also don't import templates in the javascript files in our current build; we use a callback in the templateUrl to return a string.

```
import ExampleService from './example.service';

class Example() {
    constructor(private exampleService: ExampleService) {

    }
    ...
}

export const component = {
    bindings: {},
    controller: Example,
    templateUrl: ['constantsFactory', function(constantsFactory) {
        return `${constantsFactory.path}/component.html`;
    }]
};
```

Is there a webpack loader that can populate $templateCache without `require`?

If not, is there a way to import templates in Typescript with `import` syntax?

Comment: is this for angular2+?

Comment: No, this is for AngularJS (1.5.7, specifically)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not a way to add templates to the $templateCache by using `import` syntax, but you can add templates to the cache with 'require' syntax.

[angular1-templateurl-loader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular1-templateurl-loader)

Best loader I could find right now.